# Low Rank Special-Orthogonal Matrix Representation

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $X$ be a rank $k\leq d$ special orthogonal matrix.  Then can $X$ be realized as
$$
X = APA^{\top},
$$
where $A \in SO(d)$ and $P_{i,j}=1$ if and only if $i=j$ and $i\leq k$?

Intuitively, I feel that this should be the case as $A$ would be a rotation into another orthogonal basis of a $k$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$; other than the one parameterized by the first $k$ standard unit vectors.  But, otherwise, I don't know how to prove it or even if it is ultimately true...

Comment: First of all, note that the product $APA^\top$ is necessarily symmetric. Most special orthogonal matrices are not symmetric

Comment: Second, orthogonal matrices are necessarily invertible (and therefore of full rank) in the usual definition. What definition of "special orthogonal matrix" do you have in mind that allows for a $d \times d$ matrix $X$ with rank $k < d$?

Comment: Oh, I mean a semi-orthogonal matrix of rank $k<d$.

Comment: @Wassestein By the usual definition of a [semiorthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix), a square semi-orthogonal matrix is necessarily orthogonal (and therefore of full rank), so it doesn't make sense to have a $d\times d$ semi-orthogonal matrix with rank $k < d$.  Do you have a different definition in mind?

Comment: Oh, I had in mind a matrix with exactly $k$ linearly independant (and orthogonal) columns

Comment: But if $A$ is a $d \times d$ matrix, then $APA^\top$ would also have to be a $d\times d$ matrix. However, the kinds of matrices you're interested in are not square